# How to encode url using urllib

Tags: php, python, urllib, percent-encoding

I have this php function that i'm in front of developping the same in python 2.7:

```
//PHP
$actionSLK = 'https://test.monsite.com/script.cgi';
$storeId = 'test';
$cartId = 'test2';
$totalAmountTx = '100';
$email = 'test@monsite.com';
$SLKSecretKey = 'secret';

$dataMD5=$actionSLK . $storeId . $cartId . $totalAmountTx . $email . $SLKSecretKey
$checksum=MD5(utf8entities(rawurlencode($dataMD5)));

#PYTHON:
from hashlib import md5
import urllib

actionSLK = 'https://test.monsite.com/script.cgi'
storeId = 'test'
cartId = 'test2'
totalAmountTx = '100'
email = 'test@monsite.com'
SLKSecretKey = 'secret'

dataMD5 = actionSLK + storeId + cartId + totalAmountTx + email + SLKSecretKey
checksum = md5(urllib.quote(dataMD5).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
```

The problem that i found is the calculated checksum is not the same `MD5`, and then i have checked the encoded url (generated one: `'https://test.monsite.com/script.cgitesttest100test@monsite.comsecret'`), and here we are:

```
//PHP
$checksum=MD5('https%3A%2F%2Ftest.monsite.com%2Fscript.cgitesttest100test%40monsite.comsecret');
#PYTHON
checksum = md5('https%3A//test.monsite.com/script.cgitesttest100test%40monsite.comsecret').hexdigest()
```

So the slash is not encoded so an error will be occured when generating differents checksum.

is there an other function in urllib that encode urls like this one in the detail ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urllib.quote()` is often used to encode urls parts including the path and therefore, by default, `/` is considered to be a safe character. Pass `safe=''` explicitly:

```
>>> dataMD5
'https://test.monsite.com/script.cgitesttest2100test@monsite.comsecret'
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote(dataMD5)
'https%3A//test.monsite.com/script.cgitesttest2100test%40monsite.comsecret'
>>> urllib.quote(dataMD5, safe='')
'https%3A%2F%2Ftest.monsite.com%2Fscript.cgitesttest2100test%40monsite.comsecret'
```

`quote_plus()` is usually used to create `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data and therefore `safe=''` by default.

To find out whether you should use `quote_plus()` or `quote()`, consider data with spaces:

```
>>> urllib.quote_plus('/ /')
'%2F+%2F'
>>> urllib.quote('/ /', safe='')
'%2F%20%2F'
```

PHP's `rawurlencode()` produces the latter and therefore you should use `quote(safe='')` instead of `quote_plus()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [urllib.quote_plus()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus):

```
>>> encoded = urllib.quote_plus("https://test.monsite.com/script.cgitesttest100test@monsite.comsecret")
>>> encoded
'https%3A%2F%2Ftest.monsite.com%2Fscript.cgitesttest100test%40monsite.comsecret'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `urllib.quote_plus` you can achieve it

```
actionSLK = "https://test.monsite.com/script.cgi"
urllib.quote_plus(actionSLK)
>>https%3A%2F%2Ftest.monsite.com%2Fscript.cgi
```

Comment: It is incorrect if the input data contains spaces: `rawurlencode()` produces `%20`, not `+`; [use `quote(safe='')` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33174922/4279)

Comment: Yes you are right i just thought about his example should i delete my answer?